# setting up tomcat in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu

I have gone through many tutorials for installing tomcat in my Ubuntu system. I installed tomcat7. tomcat7-admin, tomcat7-examples and tomcat7-docs by following commands:

```
apt-get install tomcat7
apt-get install tomcat7-admin
apt-get install tomcat7-docs
apt-get install tomcat7-examples
```

After this setup I can start, stop the server by:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start/stop
```

I have following files and folders:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7/
/etc/tomcat7/
/var/lib/tomcat7/
```

I have added the following user in tomcat-users.xml file under `/usr/sharetomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml`

```
<user username="admin" password="amdin" roles="admin-gui,standard,manager-gui"/>
```

Now when I open localhost:8080, I get a dull page saying 'It works' unlike the colorful page we get generally. These are the contents of page:

```
You might consider installing the following packages, if you haven't already done so:

tomcat7-docs: This package installs a web application that allows to browse the Tomcat 7 documentation locally. Once installed, you can access it by clicking here.

tomcat7-examples: This package installs a web application that allows to access the Tomcat 7 Servlet and JSP examples. Once installed, you can access it by clicking here.

tomcat7-admin: This package installs two web applications that can help managing this Tomcat instance. Once installed, you can access the manager webapp and the host-manager webapp.
```

But when I click on 'click here' link above to open admin, docs or examples I get `"HTTP status 404: The requested resource is not available."`

But I have installed admin, examples and docs. I am not getting it. Please help! I am using Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on ubuntu 14.04 it worked for me using following command :

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a link for each application in webapps folder as below:

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
sudo ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/examples examples
sudo ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7-docs/docs docs
sudo ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager manager
sudo ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/host-manager host-manager
```